# Story title: Slaves rescued by their compatriots?

Tags: story-identification

A short story written probably before 1980 and after 1960 but not sure. An alien race sometimes abused sexually (using orifices not meant for this purpose) by humans, they see the fact that humans drink a kind of "wine" made by torturing one member of some delicate race (this is a third race in the story) in front of its mate or something and collecting its tears as an indication of how degenerate humans are. Then these enslaved aliens are rescued by a warship from their home world. The aliens from their home world are larger (perhaps due to not being abused) and their planet is beautiful. But as a banquet celebrating their rescue, they are offered this same "wine."

EDIT: This is We Who Stole the Dream.

Comment: The 'wine' made from causing pain to the race of *Dameii*, called *Star Tears*, appears in James Tiptree's *Brightness Falls from the Air* (1985). No sexual abuse there, though (the *tears* are a hormone secretion induced by stress, not actual tears; more like sweat).

Comment: @LSerni: The aliens that are enslaved are sexually abused; the wine-producing aliens are another species. Humans are a third species in the story.

Answer (score 3):

"[We Who Stole the Dream](https://reiszwolf.wordpress.com/2015/11/01/we-who-stole-the-dream-%E2%80%A2-1978-%E2%80%A2-sf-novelette-by-james-tiptree-jr/)" by James Triptree, Jr. To quote from the review at that link:

> The „Dream“ is a Terran spaceship and the ones who stole it are the folk of Joilani. They are a diminuitive, enslaved race, embodying a female type, contrasting the oppressive male Terrans. Many die in heroic acts to help their comrades getting access to the spaceship. They set course to a far away region in space where they believe their ancestors came from. In fact, they find an Empire, they are welcomed and treated well. But cruelty comes with power and their ancestors are not so much better than the Terrans.

....

> The twist in the underdeveloped end, where they find their ancestors drinking Star Tears, didn’t catch me at all emotionally – I just noticed it and went on.

Comment: Can you provide some more details to help those that may stumble across it? A plot summary, a cover? At least a link?

Comment: Is the stuff in boxes quoted from somewhere? If so, it should be cited.

Comment: The quoted material is from the link in the story title. But I can make that explicit.

Comment: Just a bit of (hopefully interesting) trivia: James Tiptee, Jr. was the pen name of Alice Bradley Sheldon, who adopted the name (at least, the last name of "Tiptree" from a brand of marmalade she favored.